# В Yii2 SomeClass::find()->all() возвращает объект, но PhpStorm не видит свойств. Почему?

Tags: php, yii2, phpstorm

Я получаю кое-какие данные из бд:

```
$objects = SomeClass::find()->where(['some_status' => 1])->with('relation')->all();
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo $object->some_property . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Так вот. Phpstorm не видит свойства `some_property`. Он вообще ни одно свойство или метод этого объекта `$object` не видит. Хотя код отрабатывает нормально и все свойства и методы работают, если к ним обратиться.
Если получаю объект через `findOne()` или `findAll()`, то всё чётко.

Почему PhpStorm не видит свойств и методов объектов, в то время как они нормально отрабатывают при работе скрипта. И как сделать так, чтобы IDE это понимала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно прописать докблок для `$object`:

```
$objects = SomeClass::find()->where(['some_status' => 1])->with('relation')->all();
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    /* @var $object SomeClass */
    echo $object->some_property . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: а это получается тоже самое что property в модели?

Comment: @SOFQ3, возможно, точно не скажу, нужно смотреть. Я не знаю как там PhpStom точно парсит докблоки. Я делаю так, как указал в ответе.

Comment: нет так в phpstorm не катит

Comment: @SOFQ3, катит ...

Comment: я хз но у меня почему то не подчеркивает и пишет неизвестное свойство класса. Может там что то настроить надо. Да ладно и ладно всё равно мне кажется этот метод немного не функционален надо везде где вызов делаешь его применять. Лучше 1 раз написать.

Comment: @SOFQ3, я ж говорю, я не знаю как там PhpStorm парсит докблоки, но иногда вылетают такие непонятки, как у автора вопроса и я решаю их так. Нужно смотреть, а мне лень сейчас — лето, воскресенье всё-таки, ну. Но на заметку возьму и когда опять столкнусь, то проанализирую и о результатах доложу (если не забуду).

Comment: )))) да лето тепло и не до кода ))) Удачи !

Answer (score 3):

Если метод [ActiveRecord::find()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#find()-detail) не был переопределён в конкретном классе AR, то он возвращает объект класса [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html). В свою очередь для метода [ActiveQuery::all()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#all()-detail) возвращаемым значением прописан массив `ActiveRecord[]`. Именно поэтому PhpStorm считает возвращаемый набор объектов массивом ActiveRecord и не "видит" в этом классе никаких свойств вашей конкретной модели.

Совсем иначе дело обстоит с [ActiveRecord::findOne()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findOne()-detail) – возвращаемое значение объявлено в PhpDoc как `static`, поэтому PhpStorm "видит" все свойства конкретного ActiveRecord-класса, который унаследован от ActiveRecord.

**Решение проблемы**

Поставить этот плагин: https://github.com/nvlad/yii2support – он правильно подсказывает properties конкретных объектов ActiveRecord при выборке через `ActiveRecord::find()->...->all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы IDE их видел надо в модели написать после use все эти свойства

```
* @property integer $id
* @property integer $user_id
```

А в объекте они могут не появляться если

> public function scenarios()

был изменен и теперь не дефолтный

Comment: У меня все свойства прописаны в классе. И когда я создаю объект через findOne, то PhpStorm видит все свойства. А когда через find()->all(), то PhpStorm вообще не считает полученные данные за объект этого класса

Comment: так может просто переустановить phpStorm ?